# Django footer is in middle of page

Tags: html, django, footer

I'm doing a django project, but I'm just a beginner. I am making a web page, my page footer is in middle of page.
Here is my code snippet:

**base.html**

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
<footer>...</footer>
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block title %}home.html{% endblock %}

{% load staticfiles %}
{% block extrastyle %}{% static "css/home.css" %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

and I run this page, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy3ns.png)

i've tried

```
{% block footer %}
<div id="footer">...</div>
{% endblock %}
```

in base.html but is doesn't work. same...

Comment: This looks like an issue with your CSS or the rest of the HTML which you left out.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, you would have your footer in a separate file, same for a header.
Example (header.html):

```
<header class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="/dashboard" class="title">BIM Data Manager</a>
    <nav class="nav">
        <!-- some code -->
    </nav>
</header>
```

Then you would include this template in another template. Like so:

```
{% include "base/header.html" %}
```

`base` would be your Django app, and `header` the name of the template.

So put your footer in a separate file, and include it at the bottom of your desired template.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question